# Cassandra 1.2.9: Errors reading sstables using sstableloader

Tags: cassandra

I'm attempting to migrate data from a smaller Cassandra ring to a larger ring.

I've written a script to gather the SSTables from a keyspace and then SCP them to a instance which uses the sstableloader utility to stream them to the larger ring.

I'm getting errors when trying to import the SSTables from the smaller ring into the larger one. 
From the look of the exceptions it looks like the SSTables are corrupt or incompatible in some way. 
Does anyone have any insight into this bug?

Here is the detail:

I run the following export script on the each of the nodes of the original cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash 

NODETOOL=$1
CASSDATA=$2
NODE=$3
KEYSPACE=$4
DESTINATION=$5

ORIG=$(pwd)

KEY=" 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
A PRIVATE KEY GOES HERE
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"


echo "Flushing node.... \n"
$NODETOOL flush

echo "Compacting.... \n"
$NODETOOL compact

echo "Taring data and indexes.... \n"
cd $CASSDATA

find $KEYSPACE -type f \( -name \*\Data.db -o -name \*\Index.db \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar -czvf $ORIG/$KEYSPACE-$NODE.tar.gz
cd $ORIG

echo "SCP'ing files to destination."

echo "$KEY" > key.key
chmod 600 key.key

scp -i key.key $KEYSPACE-$NODE.tar.gz root@$DESTINATION:~/import

rm key.key
```

As you can see I flush the nodes memtables, run compaction then find all the Data and Index files and tar them up for transport, then send them to the node which runs the sstableloader script.

```
#!/bin/bash 

SSTOOL=$1 
KEYSPACE=$2
NODE=$3

ORIG=$(pwd)

tar -xzf $KEYSPACE-$NODE.tar.gz -C exportdir/$NODE
echo "Importing..."

cd exportdir/$NODE

$SSTOOL -v -d<IPADDRESS> $KEYSPACE/ColFam1
$SSTOOL -v -d<IPADDRESS> $KEYSPACE/ColFam2

cd $ORIG
echo "DONE"
```

When I run the scrip Cassandra on the node contact the ring and correctly identifies all the target instances in the larger ring.

```
Streaming revelant part of Msq/ColFam1-DATA.db to [<IP>,<IP>,<IP>]
```

But then immediately fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 15:49:54,672 Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:416)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.write(FileStreamTask.java:217)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.stream(FileStreamTask.java:164)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
... 3 more
Exception in thread "Streaming to <IP>:1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:416)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.write(FileStreamTask.java:217)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.stream(FileStreamTask.java:164)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
... 3 more
```

This message is repeated for every node in the larger ring.

As is this one:

```
 ERROR 15:49:54,789 Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to seek to position 6774 in /root/import/exportdir/2/KEYSPACE/ColFam1/KEYSPACE-ColFam1-ic-3-Data.db (6523 bytes) in read-only mode
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.seek(RandomAccessReader.java:306)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.stream(FileStreamTask.java:155)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Streaming to /10.182.178.228:1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to seek to position 6774 in /root/import/exportdir/2/KEYSPACE/ColFam1/KEYSPACE-ColFam1-ic-3-Data.db (6523 bytes) in read-only mode
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.seek(RandomAccessReader.java:306)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.stream(FileStreamTask.java:155)
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

In the log file for each ring is:

```
 INFO [Thread-24] 2013-09-08 15:49:54,793 StreamInSession.java (line 136) Streaming of file KEYSPACE/ColFam1/KEYSPACE-COLFAM1-Data.db sections=20 progress=0/5673 - 0% for org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamInSession@386e5d failed: requesting a retry.
```

From these log lines it looks like the nodes are gossiping to each other correctly, but I'm hitting errors on file parsing.

Some paths / keyspaces / col families have been obfuscated in stack traces. Please answer if you can see the error in my approach!

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually instead of bootstrapping new nodes into the cluster and let Cassandra do all the streaming?